# Why do I get a ClassNotFoundException in JDBC program?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am using a JDBC connection to connect to a MS SQL server and I am using eclipse as an IDE. I keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException` but I cannot figure out why. I have the correct `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` and I have the sqljdbc4.jar in my Eclipse build path. I have successfully run this program as a .java file but now I am trying to use it in a .jsp file. If that changes the way the program is built then maybe that could be my issue?

I tried very hard to figure this out before asking but the only answers I could find were to add the jar file to the build path and make sure to have sqlserver.jdbc and not jdbc.sqlserver.

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you running the code from the jsp? Are you using an application server of some sort (maybe Eclipse has one built in)? In any case, the dependency needs to be accessible by the app server that's hosting the jsp.

Comment: I have corrected the class name of the JDBC driver class. Hope that's what you are using. Nonetheless, when you run an an app as a "webapp", it gets "bundled" in a specific manner, so that the classes are found reliably. Are you sure you have the sqljdbc4.jar available at _run time_ as well?

Comment: I am using a apache tomcat server to run the jsp. I just looked in my libraries folder of my project and can see that both Apache Tomcat and Referenced Libraries, which holds sqljdbc4.jar file, are in the folder. Is that enough for the server to access the driver?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade I am not sure that I have the jar available at run time. How can I check this?

Comment: Have you put the JDBC jar in the TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder?

Comment: The jar should be accessible under Tomcat's lib folder.

Comment: @MickMnemonic  I just added the jar to tomcat's lib folder (taking it out of the referenced libraries folder of the Eclipse program), ran it, and received the ClassNotFoundException again. I then added the external jar file again (which points to the tomcat lib folder where the sqljsbc4.jar file is held) just to see what happens. Again ClassNotFoundException

Comment: You don't need this line of code at all. Remove it. If the correct JAR file isn't available on the CLASSPATH you will then get a 'no suitable driver' exception, which is another manifestation of the same problem.

Comment: @ejp what line of code? Class.forName("com.microso...."); ?

Comment: That's the only line of code you mentioned.